# How can I use insertBefore and nextSibling methods to swap an existing child node?

Tags: javascript, html

Desired outcome:
Consider the words 'Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta'
on click of Alpha = 'Bravo Alpha Charlie Delta'
on click of Charlie = 'Bravo Aplha Delta Charlie'

```js
function myFunction(word) {
  var x = document.getElementById("Swap").checked;
  var y = document.getElementById("Delete").checked;
  var referenceNode = document.getElementById("word");


  if (x == true) {
    //referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(nextSibling);

  } else if (y == true) {
    word.parentNode.removeChild(word);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="word1" onClick="myFunction(this)">Alpha</div>
  <div id="word2" onClick="myFunction(this)">Bravo</div>
  <div id="word3" onClick="myFunction(this)">Charlie</div>
  <div id="word4" onClick="myFunction(this)">Delta</div>
</div>

<br>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="selector" id="Delete" value="Delete" checked>
  <label for="Delete">Delete</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="selector" id="Swap" value="Swap">
  <label for="Swap">Swap</label>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Just for clarity when a word element is clicked you want to swap the position of the clicked element and its next sibling? What should happen if you click on the last word?

Comment: Just get NextSibling of clicked element and (if it exists) insert it before this element.

Answer (score 4):

There were several things wrong with your code.

In particular, you can't just call `nextSibling`, that is a property of a node. You must call it like this: `someNode.nextSibling`.

You also need to be aware that EVERYTHING in the DOM is a node, including white-space. So `nextSibling` will often return a `TEXT_NODE` corresponding to the carriage return (white-space) in your source code that comes after each `div`. Instead, use `nextElementSibling` that only looks for the next sibling that is an `ELEMENT_NODE` (not a `TEXT_NODE`). See more on node types **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)**.

Additionally, the `insertBefore()` method takes two arguments, the *newNode* and the *referenceNode*. Read more about that **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)**.

Also, you shouldn't use inline HTML event handling attributes (not your actual problem, just a bad practice) and you didn't need the last `else` branch.

See working example below.

```js
// Get DOM reference to the Swap Radio Button
// Since there are only two radio buttons, we
// only need to get one of them. When we check
// it for checked later, if it isn't checked,
// we'll know that the other one is.
var x = document.getElementById("Swap");

// Get all the div elements into a node list
// based on the CSS class they all have:
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".word");

// Loop through the node list and attach the click
// event handler to each. This replaces the inline
// HTML onClick event handlers you had before.
divs.forEach(function(div){
  div.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
});

// Click event handler
function myFunction() {  
  // Get the radio button that is checked by searching
  // using the CSS ":checked" pseudo-class that returns
  // elements that are currently in a checked state. 
  // In this example, you only have two radio buttons
  // and they are in a group making them mutually exclusive
  // since only one of them can be checked, querySelector 
  // will return the first element in the search node 
  // (document here) that matches the selector.
  var checked = document.querySelector(":checked");

  // See if that button is the Swap button
  if (x === checked) {
    
    // It is, now check to see if this clicked div
    // is NOT the last one. The JavaScript keyword
    // "this" refers to the "invocation context" 
    // object (the object responsible for triggering
    // this code. Since this is an event handler that
    // handles the click event of a DIV element, "this"
    // will refer to the DIV that was clicked. No need
    // to pass an object reference in. The test here
    // is just checking for the existence of a next
    // element sibling.
    if(this.nextElementSibling){
      // It's not the last div. Swap it with its next sibling:
      this.parentNode.insertBefore(this.nextElementSibling, this);
    }
  } else {
    // Delete was checked. Deleted the current div
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  }     
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="word" id="word1">Alpha</div>
  <div class="word" id="word2">Bravo</div>
  <div class="word" id="word3">Charlie</div>
  <div class="word" id="word4">Delta</div>
</div>

<br>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="selector" id="Delete" value="Delete" checked>
  <label for="Delete">Delete</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="selector" id="Swap" value="Swap">
  <label for="Swap">Swap</label>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the comments are also helpful in my understanding for next time!

Comment: @TinasheChir You're welcome! Don't forget to mark as the answer.